# Add new item to list that have more than 5000 items

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to create a list that will have more than 5000 items, in my plan I make more than one view to solve the throttling imitation.

but I'm wondering about item add and edit actions, should I consider anything for these action on my plan.

as example if I have a unique field within the list, technically this mean SharePoint will go to DB and select all items to check if there is same id or not. is this correct? then is there any recommendation to avoid throttling when add and edit items?

Should I add unique fields to indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying, adding and editing a single item won't trigger the threshold limit.
Both display form and edit form use the item ID to find the item to show/edit and the ID column is automatically indexed.

The same happens when you set a field as unique, the field is automatically indexed

Comment: thank you, is there any reference "set a field as unique, the field is automatically indexed"

Comment: if you try to set a field as unique from the web ui, you'll see a popup saying "this column must be indexed to enforce unique values. Do you want to index this column?"